# Is it possible to replace a for loop that pushes a member variable of each item into a Vec with an iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have this code as below

```
pub struct MyOtherStruct {
    pub value: MyStruct,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    pub field: Vec<u8>,
}

fn example(v: &[MyOtherStruct]) {
    let mut vec_mystruct: Vec<MyStruct> = vec![];
    for x in v {
        vec_mystruct.push(x.value.clone());
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement this for loop with an iterator?

Comment: why you stop at the half way to do a good [mcve] ? see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `extend`, let's rename `V` as `vector_of_other_struct`:

```
vec_mystruct.extend(vector_of_other_struct.iter().map(|x| x.value.clone()));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=66805fdde18caad51d8d0319be00aaf3)

**Note :** with this way you can avoid reallocation on per push since the argument iterator has a `size_hint` information.

Answer (score 1):

`extend` is useful when you wish to add elements to a pre-existing `Vec`. However, in the case you ask about (creating a vector from a slice), you can instead do it more concisely in one line:

```
let vec_mystruct: Vec<_> = V.iter().map(|x| x.value.clone()).collect();
```

When `V.iter()` is an [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html), as it is when `V` is a slice, this will always allocate exactly the right amount of space.